# In ASP.Net how can you update a database after sending a HttpResponse

Tags: asp.net, database, performance, httpresponse

I am new to ASP.Net coding and have written a simple website.

The client sends a POST to my website. The post data is used to perform an update to my database, and save an image on the website. The Response to the client is very simple and could be sent before the database is updated or the image is saved.

My website is currently set up using the Page_Load method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadData uploadData = new UploadData(Request);

    if (uploadData.isValid)
    {
        UploadDataToDB(uploadData);
        SaveImage();
    }    
}
```

How can I go about sending the Response to the client immediately, and updating the database and saving the image after I have sent the response?

Comment: Before answering, I'd ask: what happens if saving to the database fails?  Would you still want the same response to go to your client?

Comment: or what happens if the app domain is recycled the instant the response is sent? Or what about managing the threading necessary to do this? or... etc... My point: don't do this.

Comment: @Dan - It doesn't matter if saving to the database fails, the return statement is the same.

Comment: @Andrew - That's why I'm asking, I am not sure how to do this and would like to know a good approach. I have to use POST though because the client is created using Unity and the library only provides a simple web api that can do POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax to start async saving using page method which calls a web service or other backend logic. do the db update and image save in backend. if it fails with ajax you have the onError method to notify the user on UI but UI will never be blocked with this approach.

Comment: I created a .asmx webservice file, then moved all my database and file saving code into the .asmx file. The Page_Load method then simply called the webservice method, passing in the Request data.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code in a separate thread (either use a `Task` or create your own threaded queue of work, depending on how much load this is going to see), you can start the work and allow `Page_Load` to return.